# Entity framework: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am struggling several hours on this issue.
I am working on Entity framework project. this is basically a window service appication.

when it tries to connect to database it gives following exception

> *System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open
>   database "XXX" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed
>   for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.*

database is located my local PC.

connection string:

```
data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=XXX;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

from SQL server I have added **'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'** login as well and for my XXX database I have added that user.

but still the exception comes. how to fix this??

Comment: What permissions does this user have in the database?

Comment: maybe you didn't give all the required permissions to access the specific xxx database??

Comment: @PatrickHofman- now it only for connect

Comment: Try specify the `AttachDbFilename` property: `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YourDatabase.mdf`